# Filter null bands from Image Collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I have created an Image collection (say Var MIC) of monthly mean data from a larger image collection (say Var LIC).
The created image collection MIC have some images with no bands due to no scene presents in initial LIC image collection.

How to filter out images from MIC with no image/bands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can map over a list of entire collection for checking, for each element in the list, if `.bandNames().size()` corresponds to number bands in original series. I tried my approach with an Image Collection of 124 images (Sentinel 2) where I arbitrarily added a created empty image to get 125 elements. Original images have 23 bands and empty band, by default, only one. So, when the list with added image is mapped with function in following script, a new list is created with images with bands number equal to 23  and zeros otherwise. It is easy to delete these zeroes in a new list for producing a new Image Collection with only 23 bands for each image as in my case. Complete [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f2e6390f2c1d07fbbde7edf67fe38c80) looks as follows:

```
var fc = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.60946499778431, 36.501117552980226],
          [-104.60946499778431, 35.86265852547925],
          [-103.45590054465931, 35.86265852547925],
          [-103.45590054465931, 36.501117552980226]]], null, false);

var image_collection = "COPERNICUS/S2_SR";//image collection.
var first_date       = '2019-06-01'; // First date in image collection
var last_date        = '2019-10-10' ;// Last date in image collection
    
//var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(user_account+folder+shpfile_name).sort('Spatial_ID');
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection)
        .filterDate(first_date, last_date)
        .filterBounds(fc)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 18);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(S2);

var listOfImages = S2.toList(S2.size());

var img = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(34));

print("Bands Number in a normal image", img.bandNames().size());

//creating an empty image
var empty_img = ee.Image();

print("Bands Number in a empty image", empty_img.bandNames().size());

print("List of images in collection", listOfImages);

//Adding empty image to list
listOfImages = listOfImages.add(empty_img);

print("List of images + empy image", listOfImages);

var newList = listOfImages.map(function comprobeBandsNumber(ele){
  
  var new_list = ee.List([]); 
  
  var count = ee.Image(ele).bandNames().size();
  
  var comp = ee.Algorithms.If(count.eq(23), ele, 0);
  
  new_list = new_list.add(comp);
  
  return new_list;
  
}).flatten();

//removing zeroes in new list
newList = newList.removeAll([0]);

print("new list", newList);

//creating new collection
var MIC = ee.ImageCollection(newList);

print("Collection MIC", MIC);
```